# How to make a gray background for questions

Tags: support, markdown, formatting

Instead of putting an image to type up a question, how do I get the gray background? For example here:

[FAQ for math.stackexchange](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange)

It isn't a question, but I want that background?

> JL guessing: Like this?

Comment: Sorry about mutilating your question, but I wanted to make sure what you are asking about. And at the same time let you see the source code.

Comment: If you want to see how a question was formatted, you can click on "edit" (even if you don't intend to modify it). This lets you see the source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Markdown Help Page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/editing-help), is useful for editing tricks that are not MathJax related.  It mentions in [Simple Blockquotes](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) that putting `>` in front of a line creates a blockquote.

> Sample Blockquoted line.

There is also a section on [Advanced Blockquotes](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#advanced-blockquotes).

Comment: Yes, but this doesnt work sometimes?

Comment: @Lebes: In which case?